# Azure Application Insights - availability testing with basic auth?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to setup availability testing (URL Ping Test) with [Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-web-app-availability) on an endpoint that requires basic authentication. It seems that the standard approach with
`https://username:password@myendpoint.com` isn't accepted by Azure (error message says that the URL is malformed and maybe I am missing https/http at the beginning).

Is there any other way to achieve this except of using multi-step web test or Azure Functions, assuming I want to stay in Azure ecosystem? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing the basic auth credentials in the URL has been deprecated by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.1) (Here is a snippet from the RFC)

> **3.2.1.  User Information**
>
> The userinfo subcomponent may consist of a user name and,
> optionally,    scheme-specific information about how to gain
> authorization to access    the resource.  The user information, if
> present, is followed by a    commercial at-sign ("@") that delimits it
> from the host.
>
> ```
>   userinfo    = *( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" )
> ```
>
> **Use of the format "user:password" in the userinfo field is deprecated.**

The alternate would be to use the **Authorization** header to pass the credentials. Here is a snippet from [Wikipedia (Basic Auth)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) on how this header is constructed.

> The Authorization field is constructed as follows:[6]
>
> 1. The username and password are combined with a single colon. (:)
> 2. The resulting string is encoded into an octet sequence.[7]
> 3. The resulting string is encoded using a variant of Base64.[8]
> 4. The authorization method and a space is then prepended to the encoded string, separated with a space (e.g. "Basic ").
>
> **For example**, if the browser uses **Aladdin** as the *username* and **OpenSesame** as the *password*, then the field's value is the *base64-encoding* of **Aladdin:OpenSesame**, or **`QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l`**. Then the Authorization header will appear as:
>
> ```
> Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l
> ```

You can create a **Web Test** file in **Visual Studio Enterprise** and then upload it in **Application insights** and use that. Refer this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-web-app-availability

1. In Visual Studio Enterprise, You can create a WebTest project.
2. Right Click on your project name and select **Add Request**.
   [image]
3. Now right click on the link and select **Add Header**.
   [image]
4. You can add the headers as per your requirement.
   [image]
5. When you review the .webtest file you will see that the **Headers** section gets appended under **Requests**.

> ```
> <Request>
>   <Headers>
>     <Header Name="Authorization" Value="Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l" />
>   </Headers>
> </Request>
> ```

Comment: thanks, I am aware that I will be able to make it work with web tests, but I would prefer not to go as far for such a simple task. So no way to achieve this with simple URL ping?

Comment: Nope not for basic auth. I don't think so.

Comment: In fact when authentication is involved it is no longer a simple ping test. So you will have to add headers to your request

Comment: well, it's just a definition of a simple ping test :D Thanks anyway

Comment: Then it is just a difference of definition. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ping test should be relatively simple, there are currently several possibilities to prevent such url from anonymous access, like policies or action filters.

#### Policy-based authorization

Let's create a simple policy that requires a Secret key in the query string.

First, create the requirement with handler e.g.:

```
public class HasSecretKeyRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}

public class HasSecretKeyRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<HasSecretKeyRequirement>
{
   private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
   private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

   public HasSecretKeyRequirementHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IConfiguration configuration)
   {
       _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
       _configuration = configuration;
   }

   protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, HasApiKeyRequirement requirement)
   {
       var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
            
       if (httpContext == null)
       {
           context.Fail();
           return Task.CompletedTask;
       }
            
       if (httpContext.Request.Query.TryGetValue("SecretKey", out extractedSecretKey))
       {
           var secretKey= _configuration.GetValue<string>("SecretKey");
 
           if (secretKey.Equals(extractedSecretKey))
           {
               context.Succeed(requirement);
               return Task.CompletedTask;
           }
        }
            
        httpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                    
        context.Fail();
        return Task.CompletedTask;  
    }
}
```

Then create a new policy with requirement and register requirement handler:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
   options.AddPolicy("HasSecretKey", policy =>
      policy.Requirements.Add(new HasSecretKeyRequirement()));
);

services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, HasSecretKeyRequirementHandler>();
```

Apply policy to your ping endpoint:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "HasSecretKey")]
[HttpGet("api/ping")]
public IActionResult Ping()
{
   return Ok();
}
```

Finallddd configure your availability test:

```
https://yourapi.com/api/ping?SecretKey=yoursecretkey
```

This is just an example, you can create your own requirement and handling logic. You can reuse these policies in your application, e.g. in the healthcheck endpoint:

```
endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health")
    .RequireAuthorization("HasSecretKey");
```

This form of authorization may be sufficient in such a simple case, but definitely should not be used in more advanced scenarios.

Comment: Useful infomrations.

Answer (score 1):

For reference: Based on the snippet in the answer of @kaushal above, I was able to extend the Basic URL Ping test :) I use the XML in [Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/application_insights_web_test) but you can also submit this via the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/web-tests/create-or-update) directly. In my case I needed to add an arbitrary header

```xml
<WebTest Name="appinsights-webtest" Id="ABD48585-0831-40CB-9069-682EA6BB3583" Enabled="True" CssProjectStructure="" CssIteration="" Timeout="30" WorkItemIds="" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010" Description="" CredentialUserName="" CredentialPassword="" PreAuthenticate="True" Proxy="default" StopOnError="False" RecordedResultFile="" ResultsLocale="">
  <Items>
    <Request Method="GET" Guid="a5f10126-e4cd-570d-961c-cea43999a200" Version="1.1" Url="https://example.com/health/stamp" ThinkTime="0" Timeout="30" ParseDependentRequests="False" FollowRedirects="False" RecordResult="True" Cache="False" ResponseTimeGoal="0" Encoding="utf-8" ExpectedHttpStatusCode="200" ExpectedResponseUrl="" ReportingName="" IgnoreHttpStatusCode="False">
      <Headers>
        <Header Name="X-Azure-FDID" Value="xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxx" />
      </Headers>
  </Request>
  </Items>
</WebTest>
```

I didn't find this documented anywhere but works just as expected for me.

Comment: were you able to deploy the usage of a header with Terraform? It's not working on my end. I looked into creating a Standard Test (Preview) and this does seem to support headers, but it's not available on Terraform yet.

Comment: @Jorn.Beyers yes, here you go https://gist.github.com/sebader/d2de7069053627ccc2df8964d035f7e5